# Is there an algorithm or formula that does not involve trial and error to find all solutions to this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I'm trying to write a program that outputs all solutions to the following problem, given any $s$:

$$s = n(a + b) + b$$

$$n,a,b,s\in\mathbb{Z}^*$$

However, I can't seem to find any simple way to generate solutions rather than just trying all values within the possible range. I must be missing something obvious, this is such a frustratingly simple problem!

Comment: By $\mathbb Z^*$ do you mean positive integers, or just nonzero integers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Non-negative. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $a+b$ with the letter $c$.
If $c$ is a factor of $s$, you have two solutions: $$a=0,b=c,n=s/c-1 \text{ or }\\a=c,b=0,n=s/c$$
Otherwise it is ordinary division with remainder.  $b$ is the remainder, $a=c-b$, $n=\lfloor s/c\rfloor$